# Bootstrap grid system: Auto-aligning of rows and columns when any column is made hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a dashboard & using bootstrap for responsive layout design. The problem I'm facing here is:
We'll be having a button on the div/column, onclick hides that particular div/column.
And the need is, once we hide the column in a particular row, the column in the next row should appear in this row.
For Ex: 
 
        | A | B |
         | C | D |
here lets take A B C D are the columns.
If the column B is made hidden, I should get
| A | C |
| D | 
 
And if the column A is made hidden. I should get 
| B | C |
| D |

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="container">   
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="a">A</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="b" style="display:none;">B</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="c">C</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="d">D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you hide now a column (in my example `b`), it will move up then.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to spare the row / row-fluid divs and just go with `col-lg-6` classes.

Instead of

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
  </div>
</div>
```

You just use

```html
<div class="col-lg-6">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
</div>
```

I dont know if there are negative side effects, but it works fine for me.